# Can I perform an outer join on a variable using EclipseLink?

Tags: sql, jpa, eclipselink

I have two tables T1 and T2 and I want to achieve something like this:

```
Select * from t1 left outer join t2 on (t1.id = t2.id and t2.x = :val) where t2.x is null or t2.x = :val
```

I have entities for T1 and T2.

In T1:

```
 @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
 protected T2 t2;
```

I tried the following JPA query:

```
SELECT t1 FROM T1 LEFT JOIN t.t1 t2 WHERE t2.x IS NULL OR t2.x = :val
```

but it does not give me what I want. The problem is that when I have a matching record in T2 for a certain ID, I will receive result only for one T2.X value. I need result for all any value, even if it is null.

The generated SQL is similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM T1 t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 t2 ON (t2.ID = t1.ID) WHERE ((t2.X IS NULL) OR (t2.X = ?))
```

Why I need this? I have some detail info in T1 and the same info may be available in T2. The information in T2 is with preference. If the data is not available in T2 I just use the default one in T1.

May be I am looking in the wrong direction. So any ideas on solving this are welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

EclipseLink added ON clause support in 2.4,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#ON